# Возвращение значений метода java

Tags: java

Есть метод который меняет местами первый и последний элемент массива,он возвращает значение первого элемента, можно как нибудь возвращать два значения? 
или нужно писать два разных метода? в гугле ничего конкретного не нашел(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[] = new int[]{1,5,3,6,2,5,4};

    System.out.println(replacePlaces(array1));

}

public static int replacePlaces(int [] array){

    int firstElement = array[0];
    array[0] = array[array.length-1];
    array[array.length-1] = firstElement;


    return firstElement;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам возвращать элементы? Возвращайте весь массив.

Comment: Я сначала так и пытался но мне выдавало Error:(22, 16) java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int , сейчас попробовал чет нащелкал получилось, спасибо как всегда выручили)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возвращайте весь массив:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[] = new int[]{1,5,3,6,2,5,4};
    array1 = replacePlaces(array1);
    System.out.println("" + array1[0] + " " + array1[array1.length-1]);

}

public static int[] replacePlaces(int [] array){

    int firstElement = array[0];
    array[0] = array[array.length-1];
    array[array.length-1] = firstElement;


    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю, зачем именно 2, но вот:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[] = new int[]{1,5,3,6,2,5,4};

    MyData data = replacePlaces(array1);
    System.out.println(data.first + ", " + data.second);

}

public static MyData replacePlaces(int [] array){

    int firstElement = array[0];
    array[0] = array[array.length-1];
    array[array.length-1] = firstElement;


    return new MyData(firstElement, array[array.length-1]);
}

public class MyData{
   public int first;
   public int second;
   public MyData(int first, int second){
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
   }
}
```